# Kubernetes "Non Stop long running operations" deployment?

Tags: .net, kubernetes

For the sake of simplicity let's say that I have my C#, .net 8 API deployed on Kube using the tag "v1". also for simplicity, deployment has only 2 pods.

Is it possible (on a Out-Of-The-Box manner) to, when deploying my "v2", actually create 2 new pods, have the ingress direct new traffic to these new pods and only kill the original 2 pods complete the pending work?

Currently, my problem is that there might be several long-running activities being carried out, that my users will be frustrated when those are not delivered within the SLA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes offers a deployment strategy called "**Rolling Update**" which allows you to update your application by gradually replacing pods with newer versions. This ensures minimal interruption to existing traffic.

Kubernetes will launch 2 new pods with the v2 image tagged "v2". Your ingress controller (assuming you're using one) will typically continue routing traffic to all healthy pods (both v1 and v2). Kubernetes will then gracefully terminate the old v1 pods one by one, allowing them to complete any ongoing long-running activities. Once all v1 pods are terminated and the new v2 pods are healthy, the deployment is complete.

Your users won't experience any downtime during the deployment and long-running activities in the v1 pods will be allowed to finish before termination.

See this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/#:%7E:text=A%20rolling%20update%20allows%20a,before%20removing%20the%20old%20Pods.) for additional info

For more advanced scenarios, you might want to check the "[Canary](https://blog.container-solutions.com/kubernetes-deployment-strategies)" deployment strategy. This approach will allow you to test the new version before full rollout, to ensure minimal disruption to your users and meeting SLAs.